# React file validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question regarding my file validation on ReactJS.

I have else if statement in my code. When I try the code below and upload an image with jpg/png, it console.log("1st").

```
const fileChange = e => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    if(file === undefined) {
        console.log("undefined")
    
    } else if(file.type === "image/png" || file.type === "image/jpeg") {
        console.log("1st")
    
    } else {
        console.log("3rd")
    }
}
```

But when I tried the code below, it console.log("1st") instead of console.log("3rd").

```
const fileChange = e => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    if(file === undefined) {
        console.log("undefined")
    
       } else if(file.type !== "image/png" || file.type !== "image/jpeg") {
        console.log("1st")


    } else {
        console.log("3rd")
    }
}
```

Why does my first code worked and not the second one?

Comment: Console log `file.type` to see what it returns

Comment: Consider thinking the failing if statement out loud: "if file.type is not png or file type is not jpeg, print 1st".

Comment: This question is really old, but your second block is saying `if not jpg OR if not png`, which means if you upload a jpg, it is in fact `not a png` and vice versa, so it evals to `true`. When you switch from `===` to `!==`, you also have to switch your `||` to an `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is very simple explaining to your question

```
 const fileChange = e => {
    if(e.target.files.length < 1){
      return;
    }
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    switch(file.type){
      case 'image/png':
        //('image type is png');
        break;
      case 'image/jpg':
        //('image/jpg')
        break;
      case 'image/jpeg':
        //('image is jpeg')
        break;
      default:
        // image extension is not valid
    }
}
```

or if you only want to check for valid extension at one go then you can use the following snippet idea e.g

```
const isValidFileUploaded=(file)=>{
  const validExtensions = ['png','jpeg','jpg']
  const fileExtension = file.type.split('/')[1]
  return validExtensions.includes(fileExtension)
}

const fileChange = e => {
    if(e.target.files.length < 1){
      return;
    }
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if(isValidFileUploaded(file)){
      //file is valid
    }else{
      //file is invalid
    }
}
```